# Variable behaves differently in repeat loop

Tags: applescript

```
set randomString to "this is a random string"
```

For some reason

```
set firstWord to the first word of randomString
set isThereTruth to firstWord = "this" 
display dialog isThereTruth
```

returns true but

```
repeat with x in words of randomString
     display dialog x
     set isThisTruth to x = "this"
     display dialog isThisTruth
end repeat
```

returns false

I'm pretty new to applescript so sorry for the silly question, but it has been difficult to search for the answer, and maybe someone else has run into this problem.

I tried testing to make sure (though I can't imagine why it wouldn't be) the variable is a string, but I'm pretty sure my method for testing why kind of a variable a variable is doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

When you construct your repeat loop like you have, then x is only a reference to the word (something like a memory pointer). And the "reference to x", the pointer to the location of x in memory, does not equal "this". To get the actual word from the reference you have to get the "contents" of it. So using that, this will work as you  expect...

```
repeat with x in words of randomString
    display dialog (contents of x)
    set isThisTruth to (contents of x = "this")
    display dialog isThisTruth as text
end repeat
```

The alternate way to write your repeat loop so you get the actual value in the first place is like this. So either will work.

```
repeat with i from 1 to count of words of randomString
    set x to item i of (words of randomString)
    display dialog x
    set isThisTruth to x = "this"
    display dialog isThisTruth as text
end repeat
```

Notice that "display dialog" only displays strings. It cannot display a boolean value, a number etc. Only strings. As such applescript is fixing an error in your code when you "display dialog isThisTruth". It's coercing isThisTruth to a string and then displaying it.

That's why when you use in your repeat loop "display dialog x" it displays the correct word. It's coercing the "reference to x" into a string and then displaying it.

NOTE: the way I explained references is how I think about them. It doesn't work exactly that way but it's easier for me to think about them this way and the outcome is the same. If you want to learn more about them [here's a link](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.22/22.03/AdvAppleScript/index.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew the display dialog was just showing me the coerced information, but I know no other way of making sure that a variable is a string, boolean, or an integer.  I know if I leave a boolean test ie. " x = "this" " and leave that at the end of a script, it will give me the return in the display at the bottom, but is there some way to get this information without leaving the term at the end of the script?

Comment: At the end of the script use... return anyVariable. Wherever you use "return" the script will end there and return any variable you specify. A better way to help you debug a program is "log". You can log anyVariable at any place in your code. To see the log messages and everything else happening in the script... look at the bottom of an applescript.You will see in the results section that you have a button selected called "Result". However there are 2 other buttons. Try them and see what you get. Either will show your log messages.

Comment: Also, you can coerce variables as I showed in the code e.g. isThisTruth as text. "as Text" coerces it to text. So you can use "as anything" to coerce one type to another... as long as it makes sense.